# Offset rows to a particular column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to offset my range to a particular column but it seems not to work.
Where am I making a mistake?

```vb
Sub recover()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim current As Range
    Dim work As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Accounts")
    Set current = ws.Range("A12", ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    
    Debug.Print current.Offset(, 1).Value   '// type mismatch
    Debug.Print ws.Range(current).Offset(, 1)  '// method range of object variable failed
End Sub
```

Comment: `current.Offset(, 1).Value ` is returning an array. `Debug.Print` cannot print an entire array, only one cell at a time.

Comment: `Debug.Print current.Offset(, 1).Address` will tell you if you're getting the range you expect.

Comment: Use your watch window.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to Debug.Print a range, hence the errors.
But Debug.Print is not your goal, your goal is offset, and offset can work like this (switch between offsetting cell.value and cell.formula, as you wish):

```
Sub recover()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim current As Range
Dim work As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Accounts")
Set current = ws.Range("A12", ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each cell In current
    cell.Offset(, 1) = cell.Value
    'cell.Offset(, 1) = cell.Formula
Next cell
End Sub
```